# How should I ask a question similar but not identical to someone else's closed question?

Tags: discussion

I've looked around Meta for an answer about how to get more info on someone else's closed question, but haven't been able to find it. If there's a thread already, my apologies.

I have a question about the British usage of the term "gone" before a time (e.g. "gone midnight"). I found [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223648/time-gone-eight) which was closed for lack of context, I believe.

I don't think my question would meet with the same objections; I have done and will cite research, and my question is not an English-learner question--I'm a native (American) English speaker with a question about British usage that I haven't been able to find a good answer to elsewhere. My question could have been answered in the older thread, but wasn't.

Is it OK to post my similar question? If not, should/can I edit the original question, or is there another way to ask for more information there? I'm very new, and don't have a sense for the etiquette of (and privilege levels required for) editing other people's stuff yet, either.

Thanks!

Comment: @Rathony That's a perfectly good answer, but you've accidentally put it in the comment box.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will be a perfectly legitimate question if you

> 1. link the previous question as you did here.
> 2. state what you understand with your own research.
> 3. state what the difference is compared with the previous question and what still bothers you.

Regarding your concern about editing the previous question:

> 1. I don't think it is meaningful and necessary to edit the question as it was closed as off-topic and it will take some time for five voters to vote to
>    reopen it. It's better to ask another question.
> 2. You can always edit any post, however, your edit will be placed at [review for suggested
>    edits](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) for
>    other users to approve or reject it until you reach [2,000 reputation
>    points](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).
> 3. You can read [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) to understand more about editing.

You will learn more as time goes by and you can start slowly. Good luck and welcome to English Language and Usage.

Here is [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll go do that now.